# Keep getting "IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0" when trying to check array entry

Tags: android, shopping-cart

I am offering products in the menuItemArrayList and as the user places products of their choice in the shopping cart, they will be added to the selectionItemArrayList. Here is my code that checks to see if the product already exists in the shopping cart. If so then only the quantity gets updated.

I have twiddling around with the code but I keep getting this error

```
    IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
```

The code is just an extract from an onClickListener from the recyclerview's onBindHolder:

```
int position = getAdapterPosition();

for (int j = 0; j <= selectionItemArrayList.size(); j++) {
if (menuItemArrayList.get(position).getMenuItemName().equals(selectionItemArrayList.get(j).selectionName)) { // Loop through selection array to see if item exists in array
selectionItemArrayList.get(j).selectionQuantity += 1; // if it does exist then only update the quantity by 1
} else {
// Get the item name, price and add 1 to the quantity
String menuItemName = menuItemArrayList.get(position).getMenuItemName();
 String menuItemPrice = menuItemArrayList.get(position).getMenuItemPrice();
SelectionItem selectionItems = new SelectionItem(menuItemName, menuItemPrice, 1);
selectionItemArrayList.add(selectionItems);
}
}
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong? The exception is thrown on the line where I compare the product name in the main array with the one in the cart array.

Answer (score 0):

This is your loop:

> ```
> for (int j = 0; j <= selectionItemArrayList.size(); j++)
> ```

When iterating over a list, you almost always want to use `<`, and not `<=`. This is because lists indices start from 0. So a list of size 2 has items at 0 and 1.

When you use `<=` on a list with zero elements, it will still try to access the element at index 0 (because 0 is `<=` 0). But your list is empty; it has no element at index 0. So you crash.

Try this instead:

```
for (int j = 0; j < selectionItemArrayList.size(); j++)
```

Comment: Thanks Ben. I have already tried that. That prevents the app from crashing. However, I am also logging my selectionItemArray size with each click and the size remains 0.